# Split Cyclic order insert SQL statement

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Source data
Col1
1
2
3
4
.
.
1000
And

Output expected :
Col1
First row : 1,2,3,4....50
Second row: 51,52,53....100
Third row : 101,102,103....150
.
.
.
Last row : 951....1000

Field separator is ','(comma)

```
insert into test (select listagg(guest_profile_id, ', ') within group (order by guest_profile_id) from abc );
```

I tried this but it is adding all 1000 rows to a single record.
I want to split at 50 records

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by using `ROW_NUMBER()` and then doing an integer devision by 50:

```sql
with abc_agg as 
(
    select guest_profile_id
    ,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by guest_profile_id) nr
    from abc
)
SELECT listagg(guest_profile_id, ', ') within group (order by guest_profile_id)
from abc_agg
group by (nr-1)/50
order by (nr-1)/50;
```